# Eliminating administrator/user levels in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, administrator

I appreciate that Microsoft chose to separate system level (aka "dangerous") activities from the general user and thus enforces an "administrator" level for your Windows machine.  However, I am network engineer of over 20 years.  I don't need to chose to "run as administrator".  I ***AM*** an administrator.  Everything I do needs is as an administrator.  Being in the administrator group doesn't seem to curtail this.  I run into issues all the time.  Here's an example:

I have a fonts folder located on the network where I store a rather large number of fonts in a share.  I want to install a font from that folder.  WHAM! Can't do it.  Why?  because it requires administrator access to do it and with administrator access it doesn't have access to that folder.   The only option is to move the font to a local drive and then install it from there.

I know this doesn't sound like much but I run into little nuisances like this daily.

Is there a way to simply ***BE ADMINISTRATOR*** and not be bothered with separation of levels?

Comment: You can set up administrator network shares by invoking `net use Drive: NetAddress /Persistent:yes` from `CMD` run with Administrator privileges. I've not tried it, but running Explorer as Administrator should also work. This answers your immediate problem, but not the others that you will come across in the future: I understand your frustrations. I often have to reboot because of programs I cannot kill as an administrator, and there are some registry entries I cannot edit however I try. It's no wonder I use Linux for general use, resorting to Windows only for specific applications.

Comment: What you want isn’t possible.  Even if you disable UAC, running something as an Administrator, will **still be required**

Comment: @AFH thanks for the thought.  Not a bad idea but doesn't fix the myriad of other issues.  It's a shame that windows is becoming harder (not easier) to use.

Comment: Less convenient for you I can understand but the security model Windows used before the changes you don't like is what's really shameful. Moving towards a more mature approach - *a la* Unix/Linux and pretty much anything else - was one of the best decisions by Microsoft.

Comment: @MichaelBayI agree to an extend but these kind of "improvements" need a switch to turn them off.